# All possible values of $|BD|$

Tags: geometry

$ABCD$ is a quadrilateral satisfying $AB=CD=1$. It is known that $\angle DAB + \angle BCD = \angle ADB + \angle DBC$.
Find all the possible values of $|BD|$.

I have found the answer to be $1$, the only possible legth of $BD$ is $1$. 
I used a lot of trigonometry to compute the sides.

Can you please tell me if it is correct?

Comment: Did you assume that the quadrilateral was convex?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention that it is convex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the angle shorthands  $\angle DAB=\alpha$, $\angle BCD = \gamma$, $\angle ADB = \theta$ and $\angle DBC=\beta$. Then,

$$\alpha +\gamma = \beta+\theta\tag 1$$

Apply the sine rule to the triangles ABD and CBD,

$$\frac{\sin\theta}{\sin\alpha} = \frac{AB}{BD}, \>\>\>\>\>
\frac{\sin\beta}{\sin\gamma} = \frac{CD}{BD}$$

The given $AB= CD$ leads to $\sin\theta\sin\gamma=\sin\alpha\sin\beta $, or

$$\cos(\theta-\gamma)-\cos(\theta+\gamma) = \cos(\alpha-\beta)-\cos(\alpha+\beta)$$

Due to $\theta-\gamma = \alpha-\beta$ from (1), the equation reduces to $\cos(\theta+\gamma) -\cos(\alpha+\beta)=0$, or

$$\sin\frac{\theta+\gamma-\alpha-\beta}2\sin\frac{\theta+\gamma+\alpha+\beta}2=0$$

Case 1) $\sin\frac{\theta+\gamma-\alpha-\beta}2=0$ leads to $\theta+\gamma=\alpha+\beta$. Together with (1), we get $\alpha = \theta$. So, the triangle ABD is isosceles and $BD = AB =1$.

Case 2) $\sin\frac{\theta+\gamma+\alpha+\beta}2=0$ leads to $\theta+\gamma+\alpha+\beta=2\pi$, which is impossible and hence no solution.

Thus, $BD = 1 $ is the only solution.

Comment: Thanks, i did something similar. :)